# Unable to pass pre-computed value to less mixin

Tags: css, less

I have a variable in global scope which gets its value from a config file. I'm trying to pass it to a guard condition in a mixin like so:

```
@metadata_line_truncate: defaulted(~"${config.metadataTruncate}", false);
@showcard_width: 150px;
@showcard_height: 250px;

.showcard {
    width: @showcard_width;
    .set-showcard-height(@metadata_line_truncate)
}

.set-showcard-height (@truncate) when (@truncate=true){
    height: @showcard_height;
}

.set-showcard-height (@truncate) when (@truncate=false){
    height: 300px;
}
```

However this does not work. I don't know why. Is there any way to make this work?
Note: When I set static value for `@metadata_line_truncate` inside `.showcard` class, it works fine.

Comment: Your `.set-showcard-height` mixin has two parameters but you call it with only one. (I assume you use some Less-port (`dotless`?), because the reference compiler gives pretty clear error for that).

Comment: And secondly, assuming it "works" (while it still should not because of above) for you when you "set static value for `@metadata_line_truncate`" - are your sure this `defaulted` function actually exists and available in you Less environment?  And if so that it's capable of returning the Less logical value? (Note `true` must be `true` in Less, anything else incl. `"true"`, `1` etc. count as `false` there.)

Comment: That was a mistake. My mixin only takes one parameter. I have updated the code above. These values are available in my environment. When I try to access similar variables (or if I set the value of this variable to content) outside of the mixins, it works fine. The value is still available inside a mixin when I assign it directly to an attribute (again like content). It just doesn't work on the guards.

Comment: *It just doesn't work on the guards* - that basically means it's not *true* (most likely). Well, it's hard to suggest anything w/o knowing what's this `defaulted` is about (not one of standard Less functions).